# Importing images in react doesn't seem to work

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to get my images imported in my react app.

Here's my script:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo-full.png';

export const Header = () => (
    <div className="logo">
        <a href=".">
            <img src={logo} />
        </a>
    </div>
);
```

Now when I try to open the page I get the follow error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './logo-full.png'
```

And this is my folder structure:

```
|imports
|- ui
|-- header
|--- Header.jsx
|--- logo-full.png
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `Create-React-App`? In that case it should work automatically. Otherwise you'd have to setup a `file-loader` plugin manually

Comment: No I don't think so, where should I put this?

Comment: How did you setup the project? If you have a file called `webpack.config` or something similar, you would need to setup the `file-loader` plugin for webpack [like so](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

Comment: I am using the Meteor framework, can't find any webpack.config either.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience with meteor. Something like this may help though https://atmospherejs.com/nathantreid/static-assets

Comment: Ahh thanks, that got it working! :)